# How do I set a system-wide proxy for windows using command line?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe, proxy

I know I can manually set the proxy via windows settings under 'Manual Proxy Setup'. But is there a way to do this via the command line?

I've tried `netsh winhttp set proxy <proxy>:<port>` using administrator cmd but when I try to load chrome it still says my normal IP. If I do the manual changes in the settings, though, chrome shows the proxy.

How do I configure the settings so that chrome uses the proxy, but using command line?